# Feynman Diagram issues with tikz-Feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman, feynman

I am trying to create the following (crudely drawn) Feynman diagram: [image: hand drawn Feynman diagram] but the code I currently have is running into issues. I am using tikz-feynman with version compat=1.1.0. Here is the code I currently have:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\feynmandiagram [baseline=(b.base), horizontal=a to b] {
a [particle=\(k_1\)] -- [scalar] b -- [scalar, momentum=\(k_2\)] c,
b -- [photon, momentum'=\(q\), edge label'=\(\ell\), loop, min distance=2cm] b,
d [particle=\(k_4\)] -- [scalar] e -- [scalar, momentum'=\(k_3\)] f,
e -- [photon] b,
};

\end{document}
```

Which does not generate the image attached. Any help or thoughts?

Comment: Welcome. // Please add the missing parts so your code will compile when we copy and try it. Thank you

Comment: @MS-SPO Thanks! I think I did what you were asking? Not sure, haven't copied code to here before. I have a lot of packages loaded in the document I am working on...

Comment: Which compiler do you use? LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @MathZilla: Fine :) // Exactly this way. If you want more orientation, have a look here, both at this checklist and the other answers: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Comment: @JasperHabicht I am using LuaLatex yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `tikz-feynman` package places nodes automatically (for which you need to compile the code with LuaLaTeX), you need to think about how to position them in a way that the result is as indended. But sometimes, this automatic placement does not really help much. For example, if you want to add the straight vertical line below the loop, it might be easier to add this later using regular Ti*k*Z commands.

An approach could be:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[baseline=(b.base), horizontal=a to d]{
    o -- [photon, reversed momentum'=\(\ell\), loop, min distance=2cm] o,
    o -- [photon] a -- [scalar, reversed momentum=\(k_1\)] b,
    c -- [scalar, reversed momentum=\(k_2\)] a,
    o -- [photon] d -- [scalar, momentum=\(k_4\)] e,
    f -- [scalar, momentum=\(k_3\)] d,
};

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(b.base)]
\begin{feynman}
    \diagram[horizontal=b to e]{
        a -- [scalar, momentum'=\(k_1\)] b 
          -- [scalar, momentum'=\(k_2\)] c,
        d -- [scalar, momentum=\(k_3\)] e
          -- [scalar, momentum=\(k_4\)] f,
        b -- [photon] e
    };

    \coordinate (o) at ($(b)!0.5!(e)$);
    \coordinate (p) at ($(o)+(0,1)$);

    \draw[photon] (o) -- (p) 
        edge[photon, reversed momentum'=\(\ell\), loop, min distance=2cm] (p);

\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Would using the command "layered layout" have also worked to place nodes along the same vertical line with the loop diagram (so the 3 nodes that would create that)? This is what I tried after posting this question.

Comment: I think, `layered layout` is better suited to draw tree-like diagrams, so I am not totally sure whether this would work with the above kind of diagram. But you could of course give it a try.